# crear archivo Dockerfile y compose para web/node js

Tags: docker

si tengo mi carpeta que contiene todos los archivos necesario para mi web, allí debo crear el archivo dockerfile, allí se encuentra el server.js , package.json

usando esta configuración?

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

luego en el docker compose

como se crearía el volumen, es mi confusión
saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Allí solo estas haciendo la imagen de tu aplicación.
tendrias que correr en el mismo directorio en powershell

```
docker build -t NOMBRE_IMAGEN .
```

es importante el punto final por que es con el que le indicas que hablas de los archivos de tu mismo directorio, luego tienes que correr la imagen

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8000 --name NOMBRE_CONTENEDOR NOMBRE_IMAGEN
```

con docker run corres el contenedor, -p es decirle los puertos por el que quieres expuesto tu contenedor.

El docker-composer tienes que crear el archivo `docker-compose.yml`

y especificar las aplicaciones que vas a querer, que vendria siendo por ejemplo

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

allí se indica que se quiere el dockerfile del directorio actual y la imagen de redis
ya hecho el docker-compose.yml, corres `docker-compose up`.

si te pierdes hechale un vistaso a
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/